# Assign GitHub issue to multiple people

Tags: github

How do I assign a GitHub issue to more than one person?

I have work in project with my colleagues using GitHub repository. If I create an issue I can assign it to one user, but sometimes I need to assign  it to multiple people.

Comment: Better for either [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) (since it has no coding element) or direct to GitHub:Support

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could assign the issue to one of them and @-mention the GitHub usernames of the others, which will subscribe them to updates for that issue. If you have groups of people who will often be assigned together, you could also create [teams within an organization](https://github.com/blog/1121-introducing-team-mentions) to mention them all at once.

UPDATE: GitHub [just shipped](https://github.com/blog/2178-multiple-assignees-on-issues-and-pull-requests) multiple assignees, so, now you can!

Comment: In this way I can add another people subsribers, but I'm trying to find a way to assing on miltiple, is there another posibilities?

Comment: GitHub's issues are fairly minimal, so nope, you can't "assign" to multiple people. Even in the API, "assignee" is singular and can't be assigned to a team: http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#get-a-single-issue

Comment: I am missing this function as well. Still, what Ash Wilson has recommended is quite a good option in my opinion. I am using the @-mentions as well.

Comment: Note that multiple assignees aren't included in GitHub's free organization plan. https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/faq-about-changes-to-githubs-plans#if-i-downgrade-from-github-team-or-a-legacy-plan-to-github-free-what-features-will-i-lose

Comment: Does the `Team` plan allow to have multiple assignees in private repos?

Answer (score 11):

Here is the info on [Multiple assignees on Issues and Pull requests](https://github.blog/2016-05-27-multiple-assignees-on-issues-and-pull-requests/#:%7E:text=Assignees%20can%20be%20added%20and,more%20information%20on%20this%20feature.)

I couldn't find any update on the topic, but it seems that Github changed the assignees' policy and now in the public projects you can assign up to 10 people:

[image: Assignees form for public repos]

But on the private projects you are limited back to a single person:

[image: Assignees form for private repos]

So basically, you need to do the already **mentioned approach** (with @ in the issue text)

Comment: This matches my experience today in the github.com/orcasound public repository, and our single private one.

Answer (score 6):

Use labels.
Create a **label** for each member of your team and use these to assign team members to tasks.
This is not functionally as intended but it works well!

You can add scope: `person:A`, `person:B`, etc to search and read it more easily

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, which is *not* limited to 10 people, is to define a parent issue [with a task list](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/about-task-lists)

[Since June 2021](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-06-23-whats-new-with-github-issues/), you can reference other issues (each one can be assigned one to 10 people) and:

> - Create task lists of issues and pull requests
> - Quickly convert text into issues
> - Track status of tasks with progress indicators
> - See which issues another issue is being tracked in
> - Automatically update the status of a task when the tracked issue is closed

[image: https://i1.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/22751162/123090900-4ea44e00-d3ee-11eb-85cb-cad7c0894224.png?ssl=1]

So if you need to assign multiple people to *one* issue because there is a *lot* to do, you can transform that issue into a "parent" issue, from which you refer to sub-tasks issues.

---

See also (Sept. 2021) "[Managing code review assignment for your team](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69383671/6309)".